# Why should we implement/use our watchdog instead of Linux default watchdog?

Tags: android, linux, driver, watchdog

I am studying Android driver/kernel. I find that there are 2 set of watchdogs:

1. [kernel/watchdog.c](https://github.com/DerArtem/android-tegra-2.6.36-honeycomb-folio-nvidia/blob/android-tegra-2.6.36/kernel/watchdog.c)
2. [/drivers/watchdog/tegra_wdt.c](https://github.com/DerArtem/android-tegra-2.6.36-honeycomb-folio-nvidia/blob/android-tegra-2.6.36/drivers/watchdog/tegra_wdt.c)

Both them are used to recovery the system as system hang on an event (e.g. infinite loop).

The first one is enabled in system boot time by default, but many people still implementing their watchdog in /drivers/watchdog/ folder for specific driver. I confuse about this. Why should we need multiple watchdog? Is any one know about the "philosophy" about this?

Answer (score -1):

Because Watchdog is used for the secure thread, with the help of this we can stop the thread so it will not be able to perforrm any longer.